# C Strings Program

Tags: c, string

so Im trying right now to have a program that asks the user to enter a string of characters and then terminates once they write quit. From there it then gets the length of the string. For example, a sample desired output would be:
Enter a bunch of code: cat apple hair shoe quit
20

Right now my code says the length is 4 which I'm assuming is from "quit". Would also like to keep the level of code beginner, I can't use anything I haven't learned in class so I would appreciate a few simple changes since I can't really change the complete code. Thank you in advance!

```
char string[200]={};

printf("Enter a bunch of words: ");
do
{
    scanf("%s", string);
}while(strcmp(string,"quit")!=0);

unsigned long int length = strlen(string);

printf("%lu", length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get each word's length inside the loop, and add it to the total.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char string[200]={};
    unsigned long int length = 0;

    printf("Enter a bunch of words: ");
    do
    {
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", string);
        length += strlen(string);
    }while(strcmp(string,"quit")!=0);

    printf("%lu", length);

    return 0;
}
```